# С точки зрения (запятая)

Tags: запятая

В правиле говорится, что если есть указание на лицо, то выражение "с точки зрения кого-то" выделяется запятыми. Но иногда сложно определить, есть это указание или его нет. К примеру, вот:

Москва с точки зрения обывательской город шумный.

Здесь запятая вроде бы не нужна, поскольку нет конкретного лица. Но вот другой пример:

Москва(,) с точки зрения обывателя(,) город шумный.

Здесь уже как бы есть указание на лицо (обыватель), но это все же обобщение. Нужны ли здесь запятые или нет? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае нет никакой разницы между выражениями "с точки зрения обывателя" и  "с точки зрения обывательской". Их семантика и грамматическая структура (позиция между подлежащим и сказуемым) говорят о том, что они выполняют функцию вводного слова и обособляются.

Те же выражения могут быть обстоятельствами и не обособляться, если они будут находиться в конце предложения, например: *Москва — шумный город только с обывательской точки зрения.*

Answer (score 3):

Вы затронули вопрос, еще не освещенный в справочниках. В распространенной формулировке правила говорится об указании на **лицо** (любое, лишь бы одушевленное), но в *Словаре вводных слов* появляется оговорка: "невводное, если имеется в виду **обобщенное лицо**: *С точки зрения культуроохранителей рассказчика довлатовских историй иначе как охламоном не назовешь*". Однако этот нюанс еще не получил статуса пунктуационной нормы, поэтому правильно: *Москва, с точки зрения обывателя/ей, город шумный*.

*С точки зрения* может быть:

1.Вводным словосочетанием в значении ***с точки зрения кого-либо***, ***с чьей-либо точки зрения***, указывает на ***лицо***:

*Москва, с моей точки зрения, город шумный.*

2.Невводным в функции обстоятельства образа действия со значением ***с точки зрения чего-либо***, ***с какой-либо точки зрения***:

*Москва с точки зрения обывательщины город шумный.*

*Москва с обывательской точки зрения город шумный.*

3.Невводным (даже если указывает на лицо) в функции обстоятельства, если стоит в конце предложения или его части и на него падает логическое ударение.

Ср.:

*Москва - шумный город с точки зрения обывателя. А с точки зрения культурного человека, очень удобный для жизни.*

*Москва - шумный город, с точки зрения обывателя.*

4.Невводным в функции несогласованного определения в номинативной конструкции, где указывается только тема сообщения:

*Москва с точки зрения обывателя.*

Comment: Теперь без справочника и шагу не ступишь. Вот обсудят тему грамматики-чиновники и расскажут нам, как правильно писать. Остается только выучить наизусть 4 пункта нового грамматического шедевра или не расставаться с ним вовсе. Но позвольте вам возразить следующее: 1) все ваши правила следуют из интонационной грамматики предложения; 2) вводные слова - это не какой-нибудь предмет в себе, а обычные словосочетания с характерной семантикой и устойчивостью применения, и практически всегда можно составить предложение, где их ранг можно понизить до необособленного обстоятельства.

Comment: Да и обстоятельство можно обособить по другим причинам, к вводности отношения не имеющим. Вот пример: "Москва с обывательской точки зрения (пауза) город шумный". В принципе его структура позволяет применить необособленный вариант, отнеся вводное сочетание к подлежащему в качестве номинатива. Здесь возможны оба решения А вот другие примеры не так хороши, в реальных текстах их не найдешь - типично учебные упражнения людей определенного круга.

Comment: Очень странное у вас отношение к справочникам - какое-то глубоко личное. Речь идет не о "новом грамматическом шедевре", а о нормах, сформулированных Былинским и Розенталем в 1959 году ("Трудные случаи пунктуации") и действующих по сей день. "С обывательской точки зрения" - не вводное словосочетание. А значит, его не обязательно выделять запятыми. Хотите обособить обстоятельство? Пожалуйста. Но это будет факультативное обособление.
"С точки зрения обывателя" - вводное словосочетание. Хотите номинатив - поставьте тире.

Comment: Точно, глубоко личное. Кстати, по отношению к Вам ничего личного (вы мне даже нравитесь), но Вы для меня представитель  формальной системы, которая мне не нравится. Я считаю, что человек должен хорошо знать грамматику, и тогда он будет писать грамотно и без зубрежки правил. И такая зубрежка - это вчерашний день,  ходунки для младенцев. Почему "с обывательской точки зрения" - это не вводное сочетание? А "с моей точки зрения, по мнению обывателей, по моему мнению" - это вводные сочетания? Чем они отличаются?

Comment: И о факультативном обособлении  в формальной орфографии  такие же младенческие понятия. Дайте его четкое определение, а потом выдавайте разрешение на пользование. Наука начинается с определений, и если их нет, то это и не наука вовсе.

Comment: Спасибо tat за такой полный и понятный ответ.