# Вводное сочетание "с точки зрения"

Tags: запятые, вводные-слова

В справочнике Розенталя написано, что сочетание "с точки зрения" является вводным, если имеется указание на определённое лицо.

Но какова должна быть пунктуация, если, допустим, берём обобщённое мнение?

К сожалению, данный аспект ещё не освещён ни в электронных словарях, доступных во Всемирной паутине, ни в бумажных изданиях, поэтому надеюсь на получение развёрнутого ответа, касающегося данной темы.

Comment: Тут пример нужен.

Comment: Ваша формулировка больше напоминает толкование из "Грамоты" (там есть и утверждение от обратного: нет такого указания - не вводное). У Розенталя же в разделе пунктуации Справочника говорится не об "указании", а о _значении_ "по мнению". Приведите, пожалуйста, точную ссылку и свой пример.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/35981/%D0%A1-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F

Comment: Alex_ander, ссылка была отправлена в ответе Sharon. Что насчёт примера, то, допустим, сочетание "с точки зрения учёных" является ли вводным в любом предложении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я добавлю еще один ответ, чтобы прояснить ситуацию относительно **"обобщенного лица".**

1) Это «Словарь вводных слов».

https://popravilam.com/blog/027-ishodja-iz-pravil-i-s-tochki-zrenija-russkogo-jazyka.html

Примечание. В настоящий момент его вполне заменяет **Справочник по пунктуации** http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum

2) **Вот какое правило имеется в виду**

Это С ТОЧКИ ЗРЕНИЯ кого-л., устойчивое сочетание.

Невводное, употребляется в функции обстоятельства образа действия в значении «с точки зрения чего-либо» или «с какой-либо точки зрения», а также если имеется в виду **мнение обобщенного лица**, не обособляется:

Пример: **С точки зрения официальных советских культуроохранителей** рассказчика довлатовских историй иначе как диссидентствующим охламоном не назовешь.

3) **Комментарий**

**Вызывает сомнение отсутствие обособления в этом предложении.** Если это и не вводное сочетание, то это уж точно **обстоятельственный оборот**, который в данной позиции вполне можно обособить. Он распространенный и является явным аналогом придаточного условного предложения. Читать и быстро понимать всё сообщение без обособления оборота затруднительно.

Тема **обобщенного лица** в современных правилах (Справочник по пунктуации, Розенталь) не рассматривается. Она не стала официальной, не получила поддержку.

Такая **мелочная регламентация попросту вредна**. Пользователи должны заучивать дополнительную информацию, которая верна только при определенных условиях.

Существующие правила вполне регламентируют ситуацию с "обобщенным лицом".  Предлагается **различать вводные слова и обстоятельства**, в том числе по логическому ударению, которым выделяется обстоятельство.

5) **О правилах**

Всё русское правописание фактически регулируется двумя основными источниками — **это ПАС и правила Розенталя.** Дополнительно можно пользоваться **Справочником по пунктуации** на сайте Грамота.ру.  Никаких других правил обычно не требуется, это официальные источники, на которые принято давать ссылки.

При ответах на форуме я по возможности всегда использую именно эти правила.

Есть ли у меня какое-то **особенное (моё собственное)** правило постановки знаков препинания? Да, есть, хотя я на него, конечно, не ссылаюсь. Правило простое: это дополнительное **применение интонационного и структурно-грамматического анализа предложения.**

Я могу назвать его  **правилом равновесных конструкций или правилом пропорциональности.** Как архитектор строит дом, исходя из правила общих пропорций **(правила золотого сечения),** так и писатель должен составлять из слов и фонетических фраз   **гармоничную (уравновешенную) структуру.**

**Семантика** (смысл) предложения — это то содержание, которое автор хочет донести до читателя, это самое важное.  Исходя из семантического принципа, он выбирает структуру предложения, и только потом расставляет знаки препинания по правилам.

**Общий путь такой:** содержание —  форма (структура, грамматика, интонация) — знаки препинания. Таким образом, содержание связано с пунктуацией не напрямую, а через структуру предложения.

Если автор хочет обособить (выделить) оборот, то должен выбрать для него **нужную позицию и определенный объем,** чтобы его было удобно обособить.

Так в конечном итоге мы должны прийти  от смысла (содержания) к гармоничной фонетической форме — **равновесной** структуре, составленной из нескольких  фраз. А чтобы читатель мог правильно прочитать эту структуру, мы используем пунктуационные знаки.

А как же **правила** постановки знаков препинания? **В своем самом общем виде  они верны и самодостаточны**, то есть позволяют правильно обозначить знаками выбранную автором структуру и грамматику предложения.

**Дополнительная регламентация** (к примеру, в виде правил для обобщенных лиц) при этом не требуется.

Answer (score 2):

Мнение может быть личным (мнение одного лица) и обобщенным (мнение ряда лиц): **с моей точки зрения, с точки зрения окружающих.**  В обоих случаях это тематика вводных слов, которая отличается от чисто обстоятельственного значения  "в отношении чего-либо".

Но это всего лишь тематика. **Эти сочетания могут в одном предложении быть вводным словом, а в другом – необособленным обстоятельством.**

**Пояснение**

1) **Вот Розенталь** (п. 16) http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122

16) Оборот, включающий сочетание ***с точки зрения***, выделяется запятыми, если имеет значение **‘по мнению’** (запомните: точка зрения, как и мнение, может быть только у лица!):  Выбор варианта, с моей точки зрения, удачен.

Если же оборот имеет значение **‘в отношении’**, то он не выделяется запятыми: Я знаю, что совершено преступление, если смотришь на вещи с точки зрения общей морали (Лавр.) (ср.: С точки зрения директора предприятия, выполнение задания идёт строго по графику); С точки зрения требований к срокам дела с выполнением задания внушают тревогу.

2) **Вот Справочник по пунктуации**

С ТОЧКИ ЗРЕНИЯ **(кого, чьей)**, в составе вводного сочетания

Вводные сочетания «**с точки зрения (кого-либо, чьей-либо**)», указывающие на источник сообщения, обособляются. http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_703

Монография, **с точки зрения рецензента**, может быть рекомендована к печати.

С ТОЧКИ ЗРЕНИЯ **(чего, какой**), в составе обстоятельственного оборота

Обстоятельственные обороты «с точки зрения (чего-либо, какой-либо)» не обособляются.

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_938

«Ну нет, – возразил Базаров, – кусок мяса лучше куска хлеба даже **с химической точки зрения**». И. Тургенев, Отцы и дети.

**3) Все правильно? Да нет, не совсем.** Здесь правильная семантика, а именно указание на тематику вводных слов.

**Но оборот,** который по тематике может относиться к вводным словам, может в одном предложении быть этим вводным словом и обособляться, а в другом – быть обстоятельством и не обособляться.

**А оборот,** который всегда является обстоятельством, может обособляться или не обособляться в зависимости от структуры предложения  и других факторов (по правилам обособления обстоятельств, выраженных существительными).

4) **Вот и приехали:** с семантикой разобрались, все правила выучили, а как решить задачу – не знаем.

Еще раз даю ссылку на обсуждение этой темы

[С точки зрения (запятая)](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/35981/%D0%A1-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F)

И привожу  простой пример:

***С моей точки зрения***, здесь всё верно. Это вводное слово.

*Это верно **с моей точки зрения**, но, возможно, кто-то думает иначе.* Это обстоятельство.

Comment: Всё, что Вы отправили, несомненно, понятно, но в ответе tat, ссылка на который прикреплена в конце, как раз таки и описан случай, интересующий меня, а именно обобщённое лицо в сочетании "с точки зрения" (между прочим, автор рекомендует не выделять запятыми данное выражение в подобном значении, ссылаясь на Словарь вводных слов).

Comment: Ну вот эта информация из словаря вводных слов. https://popravilam.com/blog/027-ishodja-iz-pravil-i-s-tochki-zrenija-russkogo-jazyka.html  И на чем основаны эти рекомендации, еще  "не получившие статуса пунктуационной нормы".?Вероятно, они и не получат этот статус никогда: ни Грамота.ру, ни Розенталь об обобщенном лице ничего не говорят.  Любой оборот, если его распространить и поставить в такую позицию, когда он не вписывается в структуру предложения,  придется обособлять. Все эти правила  надуманные, действительно "ходунки для младенцев".

Comment: И примеры приводятся сомнительные. Вот предложение: Москва с обывательской точки зрения  город шумный. Его без обособления и сейчас читать не очень удобно,  но терпимо, а если еще добавить пару слов, например: Москва с точки зрения приезжих людей город шумный. Удобно читать? А если перестроить предложение: Москва с обывательской точки  зрения довольно шумный и не очень уютный город. Тоже обособлять не будем?

Comment: Значит, всё-таки ответ, данный tat, является неправильным. Хорошо, спасибо огромное! Думаю, больше не буду ничего усложнять, особенно если подобного нет в справочниках.

Comment: Если что, я говорила о данном отрывке ответа: «В распространенной формулировке правила говорится об указании на лицо (любое, лишь бы одушевленное), но в Словаре вводных слов появляется оговорка: "невводное, если имеется в виду обобщенное лицо: С точки зрения культуроохранителей рассказчика довлатовских историй иначе как охламоном не назовешь"».

Comment: Я бы не стала говорить столь категорично: tat вроде бы бвла корректором, и она следовала этим правилам из Словаря вводных слов. Но сами правила сомнительные, они только запутывают людей, мешают принять правильное решение. Ведь каждое предложение индивидуально, и мы должны пользоваться самыми общими правилами и при этом дополнять их грамматическим анализом каждого предложения.