# Нужна ли запятая после "С ЭТОЙ ТОЧКИ ЗРЕНИЯ" и зпт. перед "И"?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

> Ожидание перемен в ближайший месяц ни к чему, так как транзиты без
> перемен. **С этой точки зрения** ключевые перемены начнутся внахлест с
> марта **и** в апреле это все перейдёт в стихийное действие.

Я запятые в двух местах не поставила, чувствую, что сделала правильно! А как объяснить - не знаю.

Comment: Этот вопрос активно обсуждался в данной теме: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452532/%d0%92%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f

Comment: Я читала, но недопоняла. Мне требуется объяснение. Я не специалист.

Comment: 16) Оборот, включающий сочетание с точки зрения, выделяется запятыми, если имеет значение ‘по мнению’ (запомните: точка зрения, как и мнение, может быть **только у лица!**): Выбор варианта, с моей точки зрения, удачен.

Comment: См. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_938

Comment: А здесь, получается, нет лица, у которого может быть мнение! ОК! А перед "и" почему не надо?

Comment: А вот перед «и» либо запятую, либо тире, на мой взгляд, стоит поставить – так предложение будет проще читаться.

Comment: А если то, что до "И", и то что после "И", относится к "С ЭТОЙ ТОЧКИ ЗРЕНИЯ", то не надо ставить зпт. ?

Comment: Я думаю, что это право пишущего определять, что именно относится к «с этой точки зрения». Если бы автором этого предложение был я, запятую бы или тире перед «и» я бы поставил.

Comment: slava1947, спасибо, согласна с Вами!

Answer (score 1):

Ожидание перемен в ближайший месяц ни к чему, так как транзиты без перемен. ***С этой точки зрения** // ключевые перемены начнутся внахлест с марта и в апреле это все перейдёт в стихийное действие.*

**Пояснение**

Запятые действительно можно не ставить.

1. Обстоятельственный оборот в любом случае относится к обоим предложениям и будет являться **общим** элементом в сложносочиненном предложении (ССП). При наличии одиночного союза И запятая между простыми предложениями в составе ССП не ставится.

Почему относится **к обоим предложениям?** Это следует из контекста. По значению он равен фразе "если сказанное выше верно", а далее излагается общее следствие.

2. Обособление обстоятельственного оборота "с этой точки зрения" **факультативное**. Здесь его можно не обособлять, так как его смысловое подчеркивание не кажется обязательным (это всего лишь обсуждение рабочего момента).

Интонационно при отсутствии обособления оборот выделяется **произносительной** паузой.

3. Но в то же время **есть причины** и для обособления оборота: ***С этой точки зрения,**  ключевые перемены начнутся внахлест с марта и в апреле это все перейдёт в стихийное действие.*

Если воспринимать оборот в качестве **вводного**, то такой вариант подойдет, так как вводные конструкции **логически не выделяются**, хотя и обособляются запятыми. Но в этом случае **более ясно** прочитывается структура предложения.