# Нужно ли отделять запятыми или тире "как частный случай ..."

Tags: запятые, тире, как, обороты-с-как, оборот-с-как

Мне почему-то хочется в следующем предложении убрать первое тире и отделить выделенное выражение запятыми:

> С точки зрения квантовой теории поля магнитное взаимодействие — **как
>   частный случай электромагнитного взаимодействия** переносится
>   фундаментальным безмассовым бозоном — фотоном.

Обманывает ли меня моя интуиция? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В приведенном вами примере возможно два варианта пунктуационного оформления.

**С точки зрения квантовой теории поля магнитное взаимодействие как частный случай электромагнитного взаимодействия переносится фундаментальным безмассовым бозоном — фотоном.**

*В этом примере   оборот с союзом как имеет значение в качестве и является частью сказуемого.  В данном случае оборот не выделяется.*

**С точки зрения квантовой теории поля магнитное взаимодействие — как частный случай электромагнитного взаимодействия — переносится фундаментальным безмассовым бозоном — фотоном.**

*А в этом примере оборот с союзом как, выделенный посредством двух тире, приобретает вставочный характер.*

Comment: Вот [тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/35981/%d0%a1-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f) говорят, что "с точки зрения" выделяется запятыми только с воодушевлённым необобщённым лицом...

Comment: @4egsFrivenCat, да, запятая, действительно, не нужна. Я скопировал предложение с интернета и не заметил ее.

Comment: Спасибо. А почему нельзя выделить запятыми (вместо тире)?

Comment: @4LegsDrivenCat, вставочная конструкция не выделяется запятыми, за исключением редких случаев.