# А с точки зрения компьютера(,) информация – это цифры

Tags: запятые

Можете сказать, нужны ли те запятые? Я думаю, они не нужны, т. к. здесь, по-моему, те фразы – это не вводные слова, поскольку, как видно, их нельзя заменить фразой «по мнению человека/компьютера».

• С точки зрения человека(,) информация – это то, что человек слышит, а с точки зрения компьютера информация – это цифры, и только цифры.

Comment: Имеется на нашем сайте схожий вопрос (*С точки зрения (запятая)*). Есть там интересные рассуждения. Могут пригодиться. (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/35981/%d0%a1-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f)

Comment: 2019 год   https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452532/Вводное-сочетание-с-точки-зрения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть еще один вариант оформления:

***С точки зрения человЕка** / информация – это то, что человек слышит, а **с точки зрения компьютера** / информация – это цифры, и только цифры.*

Здесь, действительно, **мнений** нет, но есть **точка зрения**. Это не мнение отдельного человека или компьютера, автор говорит о человеческом и машинном **восприятии** вообще. Тогда в обоих случаях это будут **обстоятельства,** а не вводные слова.

Обособление обстоятельств в общем случае **факультативно,** но здесь лучше не обособлять, иначе обособление может иметь **некорректный** смысл вводности.

Comment: А на каком основании стоят слешы?

Comment: Это я  так фонетические фразы (точнее, синтагмы)  обозначаю. На этом месте находятся произносительные паузы (но не грамматические).

Answer (score 2):

Я ба оформила так: *С точки зрения **человЕка**, информация – это то, что человек слышит, а с точки зрения **компьЮтера**, информация – это цифры, и только цифры.*

Здесь "с точки зрения компьютера" – не вводное слово, а обособленное **обстоятельство** (обособление факультативное).  Оно выделяется логическим ударением и паузой. Ударением выделены **ключевые** слова в этой фразе: человека, компьютера.

Здесь еще можно отметить **фонетический фактор:** сочетание "а с точки зрения компьютера информация..." неудобно читать в одну фонетическую фразу, поэтому пауза желательна.

Comment: И то верно, проголосую за твой

Comment: Удобная вещь – факультативное обособление обстоятельственных оборотов.  Это не вводное слово? Ну ладно, пусть будет обособленным или необособленным обстоятельством.

Comment: Тогда будет каша, обычно нет возможности отличить вводное от обособленного обстоятельства. Обособленные обстоятельства — это про обычные обстоятельства, которые не могут быть вводными. Не делайте кашу! Такие обороты обособляются исключительно по правилам!

Comment: @oleedd, мне как раз хотелось разобраться с "кашей" и найти закономерность в правилах. Попробуйте взглянуть на тему с высоты "птичьего полета". Ну чтобы найти определить проблему вводных слов в целом и предложить самое общее решение.

Comment: Вы не разбираетесь с кашей, а делаете её. Мы понимаем, что вводное, по тому, что обособленно. А у вас обособленное обстоятельство. Тогда нельзя понять, что это. (Не про этот случай, а про саму идею.)

Comment: @oleedd Здесь нельзя писать критику. Пожалуйста, оформите свое мнение в поле ответа. Развернутые дискуссии также не приветствуются.

Comment: Можно писать критику! Это по правилам сайта! А почему вы не можете идти навстречу? Вы считаете, что нормально, чтобы обстоятельство косило под вводное за счёт обособления? Что хорошо, когда нельзя будет определить, что это (обстоятельство или вводное)? Они ж обычно только этим и отличаются.

Comment: Пишите, если по правилам, но я отвечать не буду.

Comment: Уже другой метод пробую — наводящие вопросы. Раз никакие аргументы не действуют. Или вы только язык силы понимаете (что предлагал кое-кто)?

Answer (score 1):

Согласно правилам, обороты ***с точки зрения*** **не** выделяются запятыми, **если** имеется в виду *с точки зрения **чего-то***. Если имеется в виду *с точки зрения **кого-то***, то запятые **нужны**.

***С точки зрения человека, информация – это то, что человек слышит, а с точки зрения компьютера информация – это цифры, и только цифры.***

Comment: «Грамота» говорит, что только если оборот имеет значение 'по мнению...', то он обособляется. Здесь же ни один из оборотов не несёт значение 'по мнению...'.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Наверно, дело в том, что "с точки зрения человека" в этом случае неверно. Получается, будто некий человек так считает (запятая). Нужна область (*с точки зрения информатики*), предмета недостаточно. "С точки зрения компьютера" = "по тому, как смотрит на это компьютер". А с "информатикой" уже работает.

Answer (score -1):

Тире не нужны, потому что если тире, то будет чепуха из-за подчинительных конструкций. Тире ставится при обычном определении понятия. Информация - это цифры в компьютере. Но если это подчиненная конструкция, то:

С точки зрения компьютера, информация, это цифры. / С точки зрения компьютера, информация: это цифры.

Участь всех государей и великих мер, ими предпринимаемых, это то, что эти меры бывают не вполне понятыми. Одоевский.

Есть одна только общая для всех прирожденная наклонность, на которую всегда может рассчитывать воспитание: это то, что мы называем народностью. Ушинский.

Впрочем, помню, я тогда же сделал одно странное замечание, за верность которого особенно не стою; но общность приговора самих арестантов сильно его поддерживает: это то, что розги, если даются в большом количестве, самое тяжелое наказание из всех у нас употребляемых. Достоевский.

То есть:

С точки зрения человека, информация, это то, что человек слышит, а с точки зрения компьютера информация, это цифры, и только цифры.

И это неполноценная фраза сама по себе, так что добавляем, например:

С точки зрения человека, информация, это то, что человек слышит, а с точки зрения компьютера информация, это цифры, и только цифры - информация бывает разная.

Либо:

С точки зрения человека, информация: это то, что человек слышит; а с точки зрения компьютера информация: это цифры, и только цифры.

А конструкция через кучу тире, разрушает понятие, и получается что: А=B, но А=С - чепуха, потому что Β=/=С => А=/=А - что есть бред. А через запятую или двоеточие разрушения понятия нет.

ЗЫ: "точку зрения компьютера" - сам исправишь) это тоже песня, как-то: с точки зрения швабры, пол вымыт идеально!

Comment: Как же-с тогда правильно: *очень ненеинтересно* или *очень не неинтересно* ?

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр сдвоенное отрицание, мне кажется тоже нетипично для повествования, но в диалоге может быть использовано, но тогда вам-тебе нужно-с придумать диалог, который оправдывал бы таки-с использования подобныя конструкции. насчет приставки нене- - такого набора буковиц не встречалося на руси доселе. На нене начинается только ряд топонимов вроде: ненецкий, Ненела.

Comment: Я считаю это неверным. Про тире между подлежащим и сказуемым (когда не ставится) говорится на сайте «Грамота.ру». Про это ничего не сказано. И даже если бы было так, то сами подумайте, верно ли стоят запятые перед связкой. Сказуемое, стоящее перед тире, — это не отдельное придаточное предложение — запятые излишни. К тому же вы запятой фактически разделяете подлежащее и сказуемое, чего делать на ровном месте нельзя.