# С моей точки зрения(,) лучше так

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, вводная-конструкция

Мне известно, что оборот *с точки зрения* не обособляется, если имеется в виду *с какой-либо точки зрения*. Но обособляется, если имеется в виду *с точки зрения конкретного одушевленного лица*.

А если так:

***С моей точки зрения(,) надо так***?

Comment: Максим, хорошо бы указать источник (откуда вам это известно).

Comment: @Sharon Хорошо, но позже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно с запятой:
***С моей точки зрения, лучше так.***
***С моей точки зрения, надо так.***

> [**С МОЕЙ ТОЧКИ ЗРЕНИЯ,**](http://gramota.isi.ru/spravka/punctum/58_685) *вводное выражение*
>
> Указывает на точку зрения говорящего как на источник сообщения. Выделяется знаками препинания, обычно запятыми.
>
> *Если одно вытекает из другого с неизбежностью, значит, что-то неправильно в вашем счастье, ибо счастье, которое добывается таким способом, уже не может быть, **с моей точки зрения**, чистым.* Ю. Семенов, Семнадцать мгновений весны. *«Почему это, – мимолетно удивился он, – как только я начинаю вести себя, **с моей точки зрения**, как раз не по-детски, женщины говорят, что я ребенок?» – и он чуть повернулся седым виском к Асе.* А. Битов, Образ.

[**Ответ справочной службы русского языка:**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=252139)

> Сочетание ***с точки зрения*** обособляется как вводное, если относящиеся к нему слова содержат указание на лицо: *Такое поведение, **с моей точки зрения**, недопустимо. Заработную плату, **с точки зрения директора**, увеличивать не следует.* Если указаний на лицо не содержится, то выражение ***с точки зрения*** вводным не является и не выделяется знаками препинания: *Такое объяснение **с научной точки зрения** является абсурдным.*

Comment: Александр, а "по-моему" может вообще быть наречием и не обособляться? Где-нибудь в источниках говорится об этом? Это так по определению или  по смыслу тоже можно объяснить?

Comment: И еще такое выражение "с точки зрения человека". Лицо одушевленное, но обособляется по контексту, да?

Comment: @Sharon Недавно обсуждали "по-моему". Конечно, есть наречие: *Делай по-моему*. Вводное: *Делать, по-моему, надо так.* "С точки зрения человека" – это "с человеческой точки зрения", но так не говорят. Обособляется, наверно, по структуре.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение.  Я вообще-то хотела сказать: " с моей точки зрения" может быть наречием? А потом уж сравнить два выражения.  Грамота очень категорична в своих оценках, а пользователи верят справочной службе во всем и всегда.   (Вы, кстати, категоричны тоже))  Ну да ладно, не буду вас отвлекать, извините.  Я заметила, вам никогда не нравятся доп. вопросы к вашему ответу)

Comment: @Sharon Ох уж эти ваши экстраспособности! :)) "Никогда" – не правда, и не всегда я кОттегоричен.

Comment: Так я вам и поверила)) На самом деле, мы представляем себя не такими, какие мы есть, а какими хотим быть.  Да и точки зрения  надо понимать в прямом смысле: откуда смотрите вы на себя, а я на вас))  Кстати,  экстраспособности развиваются при чтении фантастики, там столько точек зрения!

Answer (score 1):

Возможны варианты:

(1) ***С моей точки зрения,** надо так.*

(2) *С моей точки зрения, надо так, но это **с моей точки** зрения.*

1. **О точках зрения**

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/35981/С-точки-зрения-запятая](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/35981/%D0%A1-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F)

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452532/Вводное-сочетание-с-точки-зрения](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452532/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

**2. Цитирую себя (из другого ответа))**

...привожу простой пример:

***С моей точки зрения,** здесь всё верно. Это вводное слово. —
Это верно **с моей точки зрения**, но, возможно, кто-то думает иначе. Это обстоятельство.*

**3. Примеры из Нацкорпуса**

*— Нет, дядь Саш, просто об обстановке на станции расспрашивал, что тут у нас происходит **с моей точки зрения,** — добросовестно соврал Артем.*

*И я приняла единственно разумное **с моей точки зрения** решение: ограничить свой круг общения теми, к кому он доступа не имеет.*

*Вероятно, так было нужно, но **с моей точки зрения** что-то при этом терялось в эмоциональности, и написанное становилось суховатым и прагматичным.*

*В лучшем случае это толпа, а **с моей точки зрения** — стадо.*

*Сколько раз за свою жизнь мне приходилось перечислять его прегрешения с точки зрения властей и его достоинства **с моей точки зрения.***

Comment: Sharon, этот ваш ответ – это ответ на вопрос: «Может ли "с моей точки зрения" быть обстоятельством и не обособляться?» Да, может, и в этом я не сомневаюсь. Те ответы я читал раньше, и они мне очень понравились, даже восхитили и открыли глаза. Здесь вы снова говорите о том же, но всё-таки ставите запятую в первой части варианта (2) и дополняете исходное предложение, чтобы показать ненужность запятой во второй его части – в другой структуре, с другой семантикой и ударением. К чему это? Я понимаю вас, вы хотите показать несовершенность, вернее, недописанность правил.

Comment: А в примерах без обособления оборот находится в конце и по смыслу никак не может быть обособлен. Один, кстати, всё-таки с тире, а ещё один ну очень сомнительный: *что-то при этом терялось с моей точки зрения* (???) – нет, это явно ошибка.

Comment: Предложения и ссылки на темы — это не для образца и не для анализа, это  вот для чего. Вот Максим задает вопрос. Он разве первый в этой теме? Но задает так, как будто первый. Ссылок на источники нет, но выделен критерий: все дело в одушевленности.  На мой комментарий он не отвечает. Вот вы отвечаете не этот вопрос,  но в самом общем виде.  Пара ссылок на источник, в том числе на мнение Грамоты: все дело в лице, которое одушевленное! Базовый подход для школьного уровня. А ведь эта тема обсуждалась на форуме.

Comment: Вы добавляете новую информацию? Думаю, что нет.  Наше общение в комментариях ничего не меняет,  Максим (очень быстро!) принимает ответ, вы голосуете за него, тема закрыта: все дело в одушевлённости!  И вот я добавляю ответ: простой перечень примеров из Нацкорпуса, без анализа. Привожу ссылки  на обсуждение темы на форуме.  Зачем? Просто напоминаю о сложности вопроса, который никому больше (сейчас и здесь!) не кажется сложным. Я тоже хотела сначала дать ответ. Другой!  Да только кому он нужен. Сейчас и здесь, как я думаю, не нужен никому.